# If statement not working inside foreach loop javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach

I am trying to return the first value which is greater than 25 from an array, without using other methods such as filter. Assume the array is always sorted.

The function always returns undefined. Why is that happening? Here is the code:

```js
function checkArr(arr){
  arr.forEach(i => {
    if (i>25) return i;
  })
}

console.log(checkArr([10,20,34,45]))
```

The output should be 34.

Comment: `undefined` is the returned value in a `forEach` loop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach. I'd be amazed if it returned something else...

Comment: How can I proceed then? Should I use for loop instead? Again, no other methods can be used?

Comment: You're not returning the result of `arr.forEach` which is why `checkArr` is returning `undefined`. There are other ways to do what you want and I'm sure the answers will cover that.

Comment: `const checkArr = arr => arr.find(i => i > 25)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use `forEach`, you execute another function for every item in the array. That function can return a value just fine, but it'll get completely ignored. If you want to return a value in the `checkArr` function, you have to do something like this:

```
function checkArr(arr) {
  for (let i of arr) {
    if (i>25) return i;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find` function instead of `forEach`. And you must return a result of this function to get an answer instead of `undefined`.

```js
function checkArr(arr) {
  return arr.find(i => i > 25);
}

console.log(checkArr([10,20,34,45]))
```

`forEach` function returns nothing, it just makes some actions for each element in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not returning anything. And returning inside a `forEach` won't have any effect, since `forEach` always returns `undefined`. You can use a simple `while` loop to do this:

```js
function checkArr(arr){
  var i = 0;
  while (i<arr.length) {
    if (arr[i]>25) return arr[i];
    i++;
  }
  return null; // if no entry is greater than 25
}

console.log(checkArr([10,20,34,45]));
```

Answer (score 1):

> The [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method executes a provided function once for each array element.

From the above statement it is clear that you can not return from the middle of the execution of the loop.

Use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop instead to return as soon as the condition is `true`:

```js
function checkArr(arr){
  for(var item of arr){
    if (item > 25) return item;
  }
}

console.log(checkArr([10,20,34,45]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for `find`:

```js
function checkArr(arr) {
  return arr.find(i => i>25);
}

console.log(checkArr([10,20,34,45]));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're passing a delegate function when calling `.forEach`.

The return of the delegate is getting lost and isn't applying to anything. To get your desired result, you'll want to exit the calling function `checkArr`.

This can be done using a simple for loop.

```js
function checkArr(arr){
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length++; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > 25) return arr[i];
    }
}

console.log(checkArr([10,20,34,45]))
```

This approach also supports older browsers, unlike some, every and forEach

Answer (score 0):

> "Good code is short, simple, and symmetrical - the challenge is figuring out how to get there".

```
function checkArr(arr){
    return arr.filter(m => m > 25)
}
checkArr([10,20,34,45]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).